# Ubuntu 18 send email with crontab

Tags: cron, email, mail

SO: Ubuntu 18.04.6
Postfix: 3.3.0
GNUmailutils 3.4

I've a script that send email to office/outlook user.
If I start script from terminal, email arrive correctly to user.
If i set same script on crontab, email arrive to user but is signed by MS with "Some people who have received this message do not often receive e-mails from "
How can I solve?

Comment: Hello. A good start to solving any problem is to have correct info. There is no such version of Ubuntu as 18

Comment: Could you describe more specifically what is the actual problem?

Comment: If start script from terminal mail arrive correctly.
If I use crontab to start script mail arrive but MS outlook signed with message ""Some people who have received this message do not often receive e-mails from "
I search online and I read that is an antiphishing protection.

Comment: I *suspect* it's something to do with differences in the mail header that trigger the recipient's mail filters (for example, the originator appearing to be `root@localhost` or somesuch). But to have any hope of answering this, you'll need to provide much more detail - **how** does your script send email? what MTA are you using, and how is it configured (particularly any *reverse aliases*)? Whose crontab are you running the script from?

Comment: What is the **sender** of the e-mail that you send directly from terminal and what is the sender of the e-mail sent from crontab? View full exact headers of both emails and try to find differences. These differences are the reason for the Outlook message you quote.

Comment: Ubuntu Core 18 (or products using the *year* format) are different to those using the *year.month* format like Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.  Please be precise with details as they matter.  There is a different security model used (*confinement*) in 18 when compared to 18.04

Answer (score 0):

Jobs run through `cron` aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop.  None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings from `~/.bashrc` are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`).

One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
Read `man 5 crontab`.

Look at the results of  `echo "=== id ===";id;echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.

Since the `command` part of the `crontab` line is, by default,  interpreted by `/bin/sh`, which has a simpler syntax than `/bin/bash`, I recommend having `command` be a call to a `bash` script  (executable, mounted, starts with `#!/bin/bash`) which sets up the environment,  then calls the desired program.

Comment: Script is executable, start with #!/bin/bash

Example:

#!/bin/bash
echo -e "From:USER@THIS_SERVER\nTo: EXTERNAL_USER@OUTLOOK\nSubject: TEST\n\n BODYTEST " | sendmail -t